# Add Pandas to_json data to existing JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask

Using Flask and pandas,
I want to add this variable:

```
jsonized = file_data.to_json(orient='values') #file_data is a result from pandas.read_csv
```

as a value to a JSON property

```
json_example = {
  'data': jsonized,
  'result': 0,
  'message': message
}
```

But if I do this, and return the data to the front-end (React), the property turns out as a string.

```
data:"["some data in what's supposed to be a list"]"
```

If I return **just** the jsonized variable to the front-end, it will format properly as a list.

```
[["data"], ["data"], ["more data"]]
```

What I would like to return to the front-end is this:

```
{
 data: [['data'], ['data'], ['more data']],
 result: 0
 message: 'data has been returned',
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need every row as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert every row to list,for example I created this dummy dataframe.

```
file_data= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

    A   B   C   D
0  25  25  43  49
1  29  12  14  67
2  66  96  95  16
3  91   6  46  32
4  48  10  27  62
```

use dataframe values and convert it to list using tolist()

```
jsonized = df.values.tolist()
```

output

```
[[25, 25, 43, 49],
 [29, 12, 14, 67],
 [66, 96, 95, 16],
 [91, 6, 46, 32],
 [48, 10, 27, 62]]
```

Comment: Yes thank you.
I directly used: add_to_json = file_data.values.tolist()